# select from some table based on results from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a small table tbl_a that is something like

| id | fieldName | tableName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | field1 | tbl_1 |
| 2 | field2 | tbl_1 |
| 3 | field3 | tbl_2 |

and I want to be able to come up with a function or proc or something where I can specify the fieldId from tbl_a and then query the correct field and table from that. something like

`select * from my_function(3)`

should end up being equivalent to

`select field3 from tbl_2`

I've been looking into dynamic sql and user functions but can't seem to figure out how to feed the results of the query into another.

**EDIT:**

As @Larnu correctly surmised, there is a larger task hiding behind the one posed in the original question. The premise is this:

- tblArchive stores the values of certain "static" fields (found in other tables) with a Date attached. If/when these fields are changed in their original table, then a record is inserted into tblArchive. More-or-less an audit table.

eg: in tbl_accounts, AdjustmentFactor field (fieldId=3) for accountId=1 changes from 1.0 to 0.5 on '2022-06-10'.
`Insert into tblArchive (fieldId, accountId, date, value) values  (3,1,'2022-06-10',0.5)`

- tblArchive was only created in 2019. I've been tasked with back-filling records from 2017 on. That is, to insert records that would have been inserted had tblArchive existed in 2017.
- In order to backfill, I have to look into the real audit tables (for previous example this would be tblAccountsAudit for that particular fieldId).
- The fields of interest and their respective tables are given in tblFields. tblFields would be tbl_a from the original question and for the example given we'd have something like

| id | fieldName | tableName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | AdjustmentFactor | tbl_accounts |

Assume also that the design is what it is and I have no power to overhaul the design/structure of the database.

Comment: If my_function() returns a table then you can do what you just described.

Comment: This type of requirement/design is normally a strong indicator of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: `FUNCTION`s also, *cannot* run dynamic SQL, you would have to use a `PROCEDURE`, which can't be used in a `SELECT`.

Comment: just curious, in which scenario you will need the `select * from my_function(3)` when you can do `select field3 from tbl_2`

Comment: Yeah there's about 30 records in tbl_a and there's a longer, more complicated query I'm hiding that I want to repeat for those ~30 field/table pairs, and copy and pasting this query 30 times just to edit a few terms offends my aesthetic sensibilities. Edit: and thanks for all the quick replies everyone

Comment: Seems like this is an XY Problem, and you should actually be asking about this other query.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately it's difficult to summarize and for compliance reasons I can't be too specific -- but I'll see if I can't put an appendix at the end of my Question that explains the motivation and describes what a mwe would look like

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction (
    @key INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT 
        id,
fieldName,
tableName
    FROM
        tbl_a
    WHERE
        id = @key;
```

This will give return the table you are after through a function.